# SQL - where condition for multple child tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some 10 tables in which 1 is parent and other 9 are parallel children.

All these 9 tables have a column named `Version` with values 0 & above. zero is draft.

I tried with JOINS but with joins I got ambiguity for Version Column.

Is there any way where I can say that any of these 9 child tables has any drafts

Required output is Parent table columns + HasDrafts (From child tables).

Is there any way to achieve this ? If yes then guide me please.

Comment: SQL Server has no concepts or parents, children or parallelism. In general, to disambiguate column names, prefix them with table names. If you want more specific help, give more specific information (the queries you tried, the table structures). As written I can't tell if you need joins, a subquery with `COALESCE`, or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care which table has the drafts or how many, then you can use `exists` in a `case` expression:

```
select p.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 from child1 c where c.parentid = p.parentid and c.version = 0) or
                  exists (select 1 from child2 c where c.parentid = p.parentid and c.version = 0) or
                  exists (select 1 from child3 c where c.parentid = p.parentid and c.version = 0) or
                  . . .
            then 1 else 0
        end) as has_drafts                  
from parent p;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have made a union and set an extra column for which table it is Ex.

Select ID, Version, 'tableA' from TableA
union
 
Select ID, Version, 'tableB' from TableB

Thats my dirty solution.